# codeignirer - Routing issue

Tags: codeigniter

currently I'm accessing a product details page using the URL: http://localhost/demoigniter/product/listing/Electronics-Goods where "Electronics-Goods" is the product name.

I want to access the same by typing http://localhost/demoigniter/product/
{product-name}

How can I write a suitable routing condition?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: This is basic of codeignitre.. you can read the tutorial and that will give you better idea

Comment: This is codeigniter user guide for routing http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project application/config/routes.php

Make this changes

```
 $route['product/(:any)'] = "product/listing/$1";
```

Comment: When accessing a product detail page by typing http://localhost/demoigniter/product/Electronics-Goods, it shows 
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: $route['product/listing/([a-z]+)'] = "product/([a-z]+)";
Can you please try this and ifit works give me one up

Comment: Sorry, I see the screen 404 again - when trying to access http://localhost/demoigniter/product/Electronics-Goods.

Comment: Hi ,
Its working
$route['product/(:any)'] = "product/listing/$1";